# D3 : how to avoid multiple overlaps on a bar chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scale

I've set the scale of my bar chart with a time domain, from 1985 to 2015. D3 displays it nicely; however, there is an overlapping on some bars. I could reduce their width, but it would be too small. See screenshot here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vyyT.jpg.

Is there any way to force the bars to align one after the other, even if it requires to cheat a little bit on the alignement?

Some snippets of code:

```
var x = d3.time.scale()
.range([0, width]);
```

---

```
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
```

---

```
  svg.selectAll("bar")
  .data(data)
.enter().append("rect")
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.parti);  })
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
  .attr("width", 5)
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.nombre); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.nombre); });
```

(Full code here : https://gist.github.com/992502bf6118da4b7b6b.git)

Thank you!

Comment: You're hard-coding your `width` to `5`.  Typically this value would be derived from the available space divided by the number of values, ie. `width/data.length` or similar.  You could try making the width of your SVG larger, but that's about it really.

Comment: Thank you Ben. I was afraid there would be no solution, you confirm it...